# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[...]'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert some dated swift code (not mine) to build for Swift 5.

This line:

```
let nodeTypes = [smoothstepNodeType].sort({$0.name < $1.name})
```

Is giving an error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[SweetcornNodeType]'

Here's the other definitions:

```
let smoothstepNodeType = SweetcornNodeType(name: "Smoothstep",
inputLabels: ["Edge 0: Red", "Edge 0: Green", "Edge 0: Blue", "Edge 1: Red", "Edge 1: Green", "Edge 1: Blue", "Value (x)", "Value (y)", "Value (z)"],
outputLabels: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"],
glslString: "  vec3 $VAR_NAME = smoothstep(vec3($0, $1, $2), vec3($3, $4, $5), vec3($6, $7, $8)); \n")

struct SweetcornNodeType
{
init(name: String, inputLabels: [String], outputLabels: [String], glslString: String, includeFunction: String? = nil)
{
    self.name = name
    ...
}


let name: String

}
```

Ideas?  I'm not seeing where the mutating member is here.  I removed the other elements in the array literal just to simplify showing it here.

Comment: `[smoothstepNodeType]` is a single-element Array and calling `sort` on it is meaningless. What do you want to sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.

```
 let nodeTypes = [smoothstepNodeType].sorted(by: {$0.name < $1.name})
```

Hop it's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Several versions ago (Swift 3?), `sort` was renamed `sorted`. Now `sort` modifies the array itself (which can't be done here since it's constant), while `sorted` returns a new array (which is what the original code meant to do). E.Coms gives the precise syntax.